# How do I show the primary key in the index for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, primary-key

I'm new to ruby and picking it up a little slower than I would like.  I'm working with ruby 3.0.  For one of my tables in the database I created I want the primary key to show on the "index" page.  I'm having difficulty doing this.  I manually put the id in the index view, but it keeps on saying "undefined method `venture_round_id'"

This is what my index.html looks like for the table:

```
<h1>Listing venture_rounds</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>company</th>
</tr>
<% @venture_rounds.each do |venture_round| %>
<tr>
<td><%= venture_round.venture_round_id %></td>
<td><%= venture_round.company_id %></td>
<td><% link_to 'show', venture_round %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_venture_round_path(venture_round) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', venture_round, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I entered "venture_round_id" and "id" in manually.

This is what my controller looks like for the index:

```
def index
@venture_rounds = VentureRound.all
respond_to do |format|
format.html # index.html.erb
format.json { render json: @venture_rounds }
end
end
```

I've been researching this problem for two days now and haven't been able to find much about it.  I imagine the problem has something to do with accessing the key in its own table.  Other parts of my database structure that use venture_round_id as a foreign key work just fine.  Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To add on to Rodrigo's answer: a foreign key is usually in the format "table_id" but the table's own primary key is usually just "id". If you ever want to look at what your database tables look like, you can open `db/schema.rb` to look at the schema. You can also fire up a Rails console and if you just type in the name of your class like `VentureRound` it will show you its attributes, something like `VentureRound(id: integer, company_id: integer, etc)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `venture_round.id` instead of `venture_round.venture_round_id`

edit from MrDanA:

a foreign key is usually in the format "table_id" but the table's own primary key is usually just "id". If you ever want to look at what your database tables look like, you can open db/schema.rb to look at the schema. You can also fire up a Rails console and if you just type in the name of your class like VentureRound it will show you its attributes, something like VentureRound(id: integer, company_id: integer, etc)

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious I'm a novice, that was a pretty easy fix...  Thanks so much!